# This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, ionic-framework

I tried to publish my app in production but I'm facing this issue `You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported`

I also added android:exported="true" in service and activity, still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If your startup Activity does not set android:exported, the same will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add these into your manifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
         <action  android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: I'm using react-native, are you sure this will work?

Comment: I think it can be helpful @SarathDixit

Comment: this solution is not working for me